# java heap allocation

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I tried to increase the heap size like the below

```
    C:\Data\Guru\Code\Got\adminservice\adminservice>java -Xms512m -Xmx512m
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                    see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
```

It gave the help message as above - Does it mean that it was allocated?

Comment: How do you normally run your program?

Comment: That's just a help print, where it is trying to explain you how to properly use java.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope,

You also have to give the either class name or a jar file name to execute.  These options apply only to one instance of the virtual machine.

If you are trying to change the Heap allocation in your application server or development environment you have to look up how to supply the JVM options there, and slip your -Xms options in.

Comment: Thanks.I had to increase in the App Server.

Answer (score 6):

No, it means the command failed, because you didn't tell is what to run, like a Main class, e.g.

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m com.x.MyClass
```

Other than that, your options are valid, yes.